# Is it safe to install Ubuntu on Windows 10 from Microsoft store?

Tags: uninstall

I have been asked by my professor to do so. But I have heard during uninstallation of the Ubuntu we may face problems .Is it?

Comment: If you are referring to the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2) version of Ubuntu, you’ll be fine. You can also opt to install the OS in a virtual machine if you would like more nuanced containerisation of the system 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *installation* of Ubuntu from the Microsoft store should not cause any problems to your Windows system. If it does, that's a bug that should be reported to Microsoft (not us).

Improper *use* of Ubuntu may indeed damage your Windows system -- Ubuntu is a powerful tool, and it wasn't designed to be a Windows application. However, damaging your Windows system in ordinary usage of Ubuntu is very unlikely.

- If you have questions whether certain use is safe or dangerous, we can answer those questions, and guide you toward safe practices.
- If you make is mistake that causes damage to your Ubuntu system, we can advise you how to repair it.

It seems like one implied concern is that you don't trust your professor or their instructions. We cannot help you with that.